# Allow only one checkbox selected when certain button clicked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have the following code:

```
$("input.edit_user").click(function() {
    var theCheckboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"); 
    if (theCheckboxes.filter(":checked").length > 1)
        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
        alert( "Please selected one user at a time for editing." );
});
.
.
.
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value="3"></td>
</tr>
.
.
.
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Selected User" class="edit_user">
```

I'm using checkboxes, because there are other options that allow for more than one item to be selected.

However, When a user selects a checkbox for editing, I need to alert them they are only allowed to select one checkbox at a time.

I think I have the right idea with my code, but I'm going about it the wrong way, since it's not working and just continues to process the page normally.

Suggestions?

---

**UPDATE on selected solution and why**

For the viable solutions below, once I added:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

in my working example, they started working. I selected the answer I did, because after the above line was added, all I needed was the

```
return false;
```

line (and correct brackets on the inner if statement) in order to stop the page from executing what remains.

Thank you all for your help solving this!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding why you're not using radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: @j08691 because if x condition is true, more than one can be checked.

Comment: Use radio input instead. This is what it's designed for. If x condition allows multiple selections, have a column for updating and a column for x condition.

Comment: Because of what Kevin B said. There are other input buttons that need to allow more than one checkbox to be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to return `false`:

```
$("input.edit_user").click(function() {
    var theCheckboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"); 
    if (theCheckboxes.filter(":checked").length > 1) {
        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
        alert( "Please selected one user at a time for editing." );

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong. You're using `$("input.edit_user")`, but the inputs in your html don't have the class `edit_user`.

## Edit:

Sorry, didn't look closely enough. Here's what you need:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
    var $checkBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var checkCount = 0;

    $checkBoxes.each(function(){ if( this.checked ) checkCount++; });

    if( checkCount > 1 ) {
        $checkBoxes.removeAttr('checked');
        alert( 'Please selected one user at a time for editing.' );
    }
});
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LWp9Q/2/))

Comment: Thanks for answering, but my submit button at the end of the code has that class and I only want the code to fire if that particular button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely works in the fiddle, but doesn't work in my code, even with a direct cut/paste. Ideas what might be borking it?

Comment: What jquery version are you using?

Comment: 1.9.1 - same as used in jQuery API documentation. Same call as well... maybe that is the issue?

Comment: It could be, but I'm not so sure. Could you try putting something simple in just to see how far you're getting, like: `$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function() { alert( 'submitted' ); });` Or add a series of console.log() calls so you can see exactly at what point it fails.

Comment: Thanks - for some reason your comment didn't show on my page sooner. I narrowed down what the issue was and posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Several things here:

1. You are not stopping `click` from posting data when the condition is not met. You can do so with `return false;` for example.
2. `if` branch currently has only one line. Missing curly brackets?
3. Checkboxes won't necessary have `checked` attribute. For instance they do not have such in your case. However what does changes when checkbox is clicked is the value of its `checked` property. This should be accessed with `prop` method.
4. `if` does not change the scope, so `$(this)` refers to button, not a checkbox.

All in all, the corrected script:

```
$("input.edit_user").click(function() {
    var theCheckboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"); 
    if (theCheckboxes.filter(":checked").length > 1) {
        theCheckboxes.prop("checked", false);
        alert( "Please selected one user at a time for editing." );
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the step-by-step. I definitely missed the mark on some obvious things there. Also, this does work in a fiddle, but doesn't work in my code, even with a direct cut/paste. Ideas what might be borking it?

Comment: @Yazmin, can you please define 'doesn't work in my code'? You are getting exceptions, or page works not the way you want it to, etc?

Comment: Ah sorry. I simply get nothing in that there are no errors and the page continues processing as normal. I put an alert just inside the function to see if it was getting called and it seems that the click action isn't triggering the function call at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong selectors. Here is the jquery code works for your case:

```
$(".edit_user").click(function () {
  var $checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
  if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > 1) {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr("checked");
    alert("Please select one user at a time for editing.");
  }
});
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/639yH/